# Renaming files off a CSV with multiple suffixed extensions

Tags: python, csv

I have this python script which will take these three arguments:

1. a given path for a directory with files to rename
2. a CSV file with two columns to map the file names to:
3. extensions of files to rename (.txt, .tar.gz, .pass.vcf.gz)

```
original,new
barcode01,sample01
barcode02,sample02
```

The script:

```
import os
import csv

def rename_files(path, name_map, ext):
    with open(name_map, 'r') as csv_map:
        filereader = csv.DictReader(csv_map)
        for row in filereader:
            original_name = row["original"]
            new_name = row["new"]
            old_filename = '%s/%s.%s' % (path, original_name, ext)
            new_filename = '%s/%s_%s.%s' % (path, new_name, original_name, ext)
            try:
                os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Rename for file %s failed. Details: ' % old_filename) 
                print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename, path, name_map, ext = sys.argv
    rename_files(path, name_map, ext)
```

However, there are many extensions for a given file with varying suffixes (i.e. tar.gz, .pass.tar.gz, .fail.tar.gz)

How can I improve my script such that it will rename the files using the CSV file while maintaining the files original extension without passing it as an argument?

For example:

```
python rename.py /test/directory filestorename.csv pass.vcf.gz
```

will only rename `barcode01.pass.vcf.gz` to `sample01.pass.vcf.gz`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `split` method to split your file names on the first  `.`, limiting the number of splits to 1.  This creates a list where the first element is the file name, and the second is the extension.  You can use `-1` index to capture the extension.  Then just join that with the new file name.

```
f = 'barcode01.pass.vcf.gz'
original = 'barcode01'
new = 'sample01'

if original in f:
    extension = f.split('.',1)[-1]
    new_filename = '.'.join([new,extension])
    print(new_filename)
```

Output

```
sample01.pass.vcf.gz
```